# UPDATE INTO rather than INSERT INTO based on a non-primary key column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Now I know there is no such command as `UPDATE INTO`, however is it possible to do something similar rather than an `INSERT INTO` based on a non-primary key column?

For example, I want to check if a record with today's date already exists for a given person. If the value already exists, then update the record with the new figures, and if it doesn't exist (say the script is ran tomorrow) then insert it into the table.

Here is the code I'm working with;

```
if OBJECT_ID('dbo.Temp') IS NULL 
    create table [dbo].[Temp] (
        UserID int,
        FullName varchar(300),
        DocsInBatch int,
        NumReviewed int,
        Outstanding int,
        Relevant int,
        HighlyRelevant int,
        Irrelevant int,
        OutOfScope int,
        Question int,
        TechnicalQuestion int,
        LastUpdate date

        PRIMARY KEY (UserID)
    )
insert INTO [dbo].[Temp]
SELECT a.UserID,
        a.FullName, 
        a.DocsInBatch, 
        a.NumReviewed, 
        (a.DocsInBatch - a.NumReviewed) AS "Outstanding",
        a.Relevant,
        a.[Highly Relevant],
        a.[Irrelevant],
        a.[Out-Of-Scope],
        a.[Question],
        a.[Technical Question],
        GetDate()
        FROM
    (
            SELECT au.UserID as [UserID],
                    au.FullName, 
                    count(1) AS "DocsInBatch", 
                    count([Document1LR_Relevancy].[CoArtID]) AS "NumReviewed",
                    sum(case when [Document1LR_Relevancy].[1LR_Relevancy] = 'Relevant' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Relevant',
                    sum(case when [Document1LR_Relevancy].[1LR_Relevancy] = 'Highly Relevant' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Highly Relevant',
                    sum(case when [Document1LR_Relevancy].[1LR_Relevancy] = 'Irrelevant' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Irrelevant',
                    sum(case when [Document1LR_Relevancy].[1LR_Relevancy] = 'Out-Of-Scope' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Out-Of-Scope',
                    sum(case when [Document1LR_Relevancy].[1LR_Relevancy] = 'Question' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Question',
                    sum(case when [Document1LR_Relevancy].[1LR_Relevancy] = 'Technical Question' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Technical Question'
                from [EDDS1024194].[EDDSDBO].[Document] doc
            LEFT JOIN (
                        SELECT XXX.ArtifactID, co.Name AS [1LR_Relevancy], Co.ArtifactID [CoArtID]
                        FROM [EDDSDBO].[Document] AS XXX WITH (NOLOCK)
                            INNER JOIN [EDDSDBO].[ZCodeArtifact_1001288] AS ca WITH (NOLOCK)
                                ON XXX.[ArtifactID] = ca.[AssociatedArtifactID]
                            INNER JOIN [EDDSDBO].[Code] AS co WITH (NOLOCK)
                                ON ca.[CodeArtifactID] = co.[ArtifactID]
                        ) AS [Document1LR_Relevancy]
                ON doc.[ArtifactID] = [Document1LR_Relevancy].[ArtifactID]
            INNER JOIN [EDDS1024194].[EDDSDBO].[DocumentBatch] db on
                db.DocumentArtifactID = doc.ArtifactID
            INNER JOIN [EDDS1024194].[EDDSDBO].[Batch] bat on
                bat.ArtifactID = db.BatchArtifactID
            INNER JOIN [EDDS1024194].[EDDSDBO].[AuditUser] au on
                au.UserID = bat.AssignedTo
            GROUP BY au.FullName, au.UserID

)a
ORDER BY a.FullName
```

This code works. It inserts new records into the table every time it is run, however I am unsure how to do the aforementioned.

Comment: There is nothing like `UPDATE INTO`!

Comment: So you have "code", is it working? No? Then tell us what's wrong. It also helps so see some simplified sample data that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Use double quotes for the column aliases, e.g. `as "Highly Relevant"`. (Single quotes are for string literals.)

Comment: I think the MERGE is what you're looking for

Comment: In case it exist, delete and add a new record, or Primary key has to be the same?

Comment: Updating if it exists, inserting if it doesn't is often known as UPSERT. There is no UPSERT command in SQL Server 2008, but http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21418/upsert-is-there-a-better-alternative-to-merge-or-rowcount lists some of the ways you can do it. MERGE, already mentioned by @AllanS.Hansen, is probably the best way.